# Load div with ajax in bootstrap navtabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

On my website I use the bootstrap navtabs. This works great. I love it that the browser needs no refresh or reload to load content. 
However, I need to add a new function to it.

Imagine a webpage with lots of products/items. This can be shown via a nav tab. However, I want to be able to click on this product of item and that the container in which all the tab-content is shown will be filled with that product information.

I have made such a structure using ajax (loading the tab-content with an ajax loaded html file). But obviously, when I click on one of the navtabs it will still show the ajax loaded file instead of the original tab-content.

How can I make sure that when on such a product info page and I click on a nav tab, the nav tabcontent is shown?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post some of your javascript code

Answer (score -1):

yeah is easy you just need to do it by ajax and make this work on click here i dummy code for your help:
give id to your tabs so you can catch its click thn JSON for each in this case 3 JSON for three tabs each for each tab

json file dummy:

```
    [
    {
    "image" :"image url",
    "cat" : "latest",
    "head" :"Without morning third,Fowl forth she'd."
    },
    {
    "image" :"image url",
    "cat" : "latest",
    "head" :"Without morning third,Fowl forth she'd."
    },
   {
    "image" :"image url",
    "cat" : "latest",
    "head" :"Without morning third,Fowl forth she'd."
    }
    ]
```

that was you json now fetch it with getJSON;

```
 $('#main').on('click',function(){

$.ajax({

    url:"main.json",
    dataType:"json",
beforeSend: function() {
    // setting a timeout
    $('.over').show()
},


    success:function(){
        $('#main_cont').empty();
            $.getJSON('main.json',function(maindata){
                $.each(maindata,function(i,value){
                    var main_data = '<li>' + '<img src="' + value.image +  '"/>' + '<span>' + value.cat + '</span>' + '<h3>' + value.head + '</h3>' + '</li>';
                $('#main_cont').append(main_data)
                })
            })
    },
complete: function() {
    // setting a timeout
    $('.over').hide()
},
    error:function(xhr,status,error){
        alert(xhr.status)
    }

})
})
```

hope this will help please reply if you need any help..make many json on above patten and use them in ajax

Comment: This isn't tab specific. Also please format answers so they are readable

Comment: i am just showing him the way with dummy code he can easily do with this code